# NgxsFeatureModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)

Tags: angular, jestjs, nrwl-nx, ngxs, angular-unit-test

Running NX mono repo and Angular

```
"@nrwl/angular": "15.2.4",
"@angular/core": "~15.0.0",
"@ngxs/store": "^3.7.6",
"jest": "28.1.1",
"@nrwl/jest": "15.2.4",
```

The exciting part is, the component I am testing has nothing to do with Ngxs and spec file is simple.

```
describe('OperationPlanTaskFormComponent', () => {
let component: OperationPlanTaskFormComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<OperationPlanTaskFormComponent>;

beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [OperationPlanTaskFormComponent],
        imports: [
            ButtonModule,
            ConfirmDialogModule,
        ]
    }).compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(OperationPlanTaskFormComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
```

});

So, when I run test file for this it shows error "NgxsFeatureModule does not have a module def (ɵmod property)"

[image]

Tried deleting `node_modules` folder and clean install with `npm ci`. Tried delete `.angular` and including the cache. Even tried `nx reset`. No luck. I am sure that the component I am trying to test doesn't have any dependency which can cause this issue.

I would really appreciate if anyone has any idea about what is actually going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for the issue. Update `package.json` and add -

```
"postinstall-ng": "ngcc",
```

in scripts. Then run it

```
npm run postinstall-ng
```

What it does is

[image]

So, it basically changes the legacy library compatible with runtime IVY.

> The ngcc (Angular Compatibility Compiler) is a tool used to compile
> Angular libraries that have been published in the legacy format, which
> is not compatible with the Angular Ivy runtime, to a format that is
> compatible with Ivy.

ref https://iq.js.org/questions/angular/what-is-ngcc

Finally, my two cents is - `ngxs` library got some issues. They need to provide Ivy distribution.